# Sort list given a list of keys?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a `List<Project>`

A Project has an ID which is an int.
I then have a list of int which is correspond to IDs of projects.

The projects need to be processed in the order of the list of int.

There might be projects with a null ID.

Any project not having an ID or have an id not in the list will go to the bottom (or even better, be removed from the results lists).

I can think of an O(N^2) way to do this but I am wondering if there might be a better way with LINQ or something that could be more m + n or n or something...

Thanks

Comment: [`List.Sort(Comparison<T> comparison)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx) will do it in average O(n*log(n)), worst case O(n^2), and you don't have to write anything.

Comment: Could you put that in answer form with a minimal example?

Comment: how to handle projects with null `id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        class Project
        {
            public int? id;
            public Project(int? iid) { id = iid; }
        }

        public class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                List<Project> pros = new List<Project>() { new Project(null), new Project(10), new Project(50), new Project(1), new Project(null) };
                var x = new Comparison<Project>((Project r, Project l) =>
                    {
                        if (r.id == null && l.id == null)
                            return 0;

                        if (r.id == null)
                        {
                            return 1;
                        }

                        if (l.id == null)
                        {
                            return -1;
                        }
                        return Math.Sign(r.id.Value - l.id.Value);
                    });
                pros.Sort(x);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }                
        }
```

You can change who minuses who and the polarity of -1 or 1 to get the nans where you want it to go. This one pushes the nans to the end and sorts smallest to largest.

Alternatively, if you don't want to process the nans at all and don't want to sort by ID, just use a where statement to get the iterator without the null ids:

```
var nonulls = pros.Where(pr => (pr.id != null));
```

Which lazily evaluates as just the set without the nulls, doesn't actually store the intermediates so you don't have to worry about the storage issues. O(N), little to no overhead.

Answer (score 0):

With next solution projects with null `Id` will be ignored. **O(N)**

```
int[] ids = new int[10];
List<Project> projects = new List<Project>();

var projectsDictionary = projects.ToDictionary(proj=> proj.Id, proj => proj);

var orderedProjects = ids.Select(id => projectsDictionary[id]);
```

Comment: Hash sort will get you the objects in the right order in O(n*log(N)) time, but I think you'll have to use the [SortedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx) type to guarantee sorted keys.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams order in dictionary doesn't matter. `ids` array dictates order

Comment: @Ivanov aha, misread OP's comments, you're right. In that case, a "where" statement would be better...I'll change my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom comparison to handle the null project numbers any way you like:

```
class Project {
    int? ID { get; set; }
}
...
Comparison<Project> comparison = delegate(Project x, Project y)
{
    int xkey = x.ID.HasValue ? x.ID.Value : int.MaxValue;
    int ykey = y.ID.HasValue ? y.ID.Value : int.MaxValue;
    return xkey.CompareTo(ykey);
};
list.Sort(comparison);
```

Comment: Pretty good, but if they have a key that is maxvalue it doesn't guarantee to come before the null id : `List<Project> pros = new List<Project>() { new Project(null), new Project(int.MaxValue), new Project(50), new Project(1), new Project(null) };` becomes {1,50,null,int.MaxValue,null}. Granted, this is a corner case.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very simple LINQ way to do it. Not sure about the runtime though.

```
List<int?> pids = new List<int?>() { 2, 4, 3 };

List<Project> projects = new List<Project>() { 
    new Project(1), new Project(2), 
    new Project(3), new Project(4), 
    new Project(5), new Project(null) };

List<Project> sortedProjectsByPids = pids
    .Select(pid => projects.First(p => p.ID == pid))
    .ToList<Project>();
```

Assuming your Project class looks like the following:

```
class Project
{
    public int? ID;

    public Project(int? id)
    {
        ID = id;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!